# Acegi/Spring Security Captcha force new captcha value

Tags: grails, captcha, spring-security

We are using Grails Acegi plugin 0.5.1 for authentication and also the Captcha functionality.  On input validation errors, I would like to generate a new Captcha value.  I am using the render method from a User controller to present the template with the validation errors.  The template in question includes an img element implementing a createLink tag to generate the Captcha value.  On the initial load of this template the CaptchaController Index action is called and the value and image are generated.  However, the render method from the User controller does not initiate the call to the CaptchaController when the validation errors are presented.  Anyone know how I could force the call to the Captcha controller under error situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a date/timestamp to the image name it forced the createLink call to be made on each subsequent rendering.